# Working with concatenated list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Currently I have a list of substitutions for specific letters in the alphabet. The letter `a` is replaced by whatever value is at the **first** index, `b` with whatever is at the **second** index, and so on.

One feature that I appreciate in Python is the ability to perform list comprehensions. However, when I attempted to perform this with concatenation, I did not get positive results.

```
letters = ["ka","zu","mi","te","ku","lu","ji","ri","ki","zu","me","ta","rin","to","mo",
           "no","ke","shi","ari","chi","do","ru","mei","na","fu","zi"]

def nameToNinja(str):
    name = ""
    for i in str:
        i=i.lower()
        if ord(i) >= 97 and ord(i) <= 122:
            name+= letters[ord(i.lower()) - 97]
        else:
            name += i
    return name


name = "Obama"
print("Your ninja name is: {0}".format(nameToNinja(name)))
```

My attempt at turning the function into a list comprehension in Python does not work. In fact, the only error I am receiving is `Syntax Error`.

**Attempt:**

```
def nameToNinja(str):
    return ''.join([letters[ord(i.lower()) - 97] if ord(i.lower()) >= 97 and ord(i.lower()) <= 122 else i 
    for i in str)
```

What is the correct way to shorten the original function into a *concatenated list comprehension.*

Comment: You mismatched your brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
letters = ["ka","zu","mi","te","ku","lu","ji","ri","ki","zu","me","ta","rin","to","mo","no","ke","shi","ari","chi","do","ru","mei","na","fu","zi"]

def nameToNinja(str):
    return ''.join([letters[ord(i.lower()) - 97] if (97 <= ord(i.lower()) <= 122) else i.lower() for i in str])

name = "Obama"
print("Your ninja name is: {0}".format(nameToNinja(name)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This calls `.lower()` only once per letter:

```
def name_to_ninja(s):
    return ''.join(letters[ord(x) - 97] if ord(x) >= 97 and ord(x) <= 122 else x 
                   for x in (y.lower() for y in s))
name = "Obama"
print("Your ninja name is: {0}".format(name_to_ninja(name)))
```

Output:

```
Your ninja name is: mozukarinka
```

Answer (score -1):

```
letters = ["ka","zu","mi","te","ku","lu","ji","ri","ki","zu","me","ta","rin","to","mo","no","ke","shi","ari","chi","do","ru","mei","na","fu","zi"]

name = "Obama"

ninja_name = ''.join(
        [letters[ord(i)-ord('a')] if i.islower() else i for i in name]
        )

print("Name:", name, "Ninjaname:", ninja_name)
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same: consider what happens to a letter which is originally uppercase.

Comment: Compare your result  `Ozukarinka` to the desired result `mozukarinka`. You should always test your solution.